# wordpress JSONAPI introspector always limits number at 10?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm a little new to Wordpress and the JSON API so forgive me if this is a newbie question but i'm trying to get *all* of the posts of a few different custom post types and return them as JSON via my own JSON controller (extending the JSON API)

if I do this:

```
$posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts(array('post_type' => array('post','tweet','gallery','video','music'), 'post_parent' => 0, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'date', 'numberposts' => 100000000000));
echo count($posts);
```

I only get "10" posts but there are a lot more in the db. Whereas if I do this:

```
echo count(get_posts(array('post_type' => array('post','tweet','gallery','video','music'), 'post_parent' => 0, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'date', 'numberposts' => 100000000000)));
```

I get "74", the correct number of posts in the db. Essentially the JSON API is limiting the returned value to only 10 posts. I'm pretty sure I can hack the JSON API plugin to allow more but that seems like it would mess up my code for any API upgrades.

Is there a way to set the JSONAPI->introspector post number to "all"

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm answering my own question because it might be useful to someone else sometime.

After reading through the somewhat sparse documentation on the wordpress plugin directory and getting nowhere. I found a variable in the JSON API code here's how it works PS -1 just mean "all":

```
$json_api->query->count=-1;
$posts = $json_api->introspector->get_posts(array('post_type' => array('post','tweet','gallery','video','music'), 'post_parent' => 0, 'order' => 'ASC', 'orderby' => 'date', 'numberposts' => 4));
echo count($posts);
```

you can set the count to whatever you want before making the api call.

Comment: I was looking for the same thing. It works, but there should be a better solution for this though in the plugin.

Comment: Where did you find this code at? What file? I am having an issue where the json api is limiting the number of advanced custom post types